# NullPointerException when running CXF JAX-RS 2.0 client "target" method in Liberty Profile under a Thread

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, websphere-liberty

I have some JAX-RS 2.0 clients running ok in Liberty Profile 8.5.5.6. They are all working ok sequentially, but I want to execute some of them in a Thread so they run concurrently. When I try to get a "target" inside a FutureTask with:

```
 WebTarget myResource = client.target(apiURLBase + ...);
```

I get NullPointerExcepton in this com.ibm.ws... class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.client.bus.LibertyJAXRSClientBusFactory.getClientScopeBus(LibertyJAXRSClientBusFactory.java:89)
     at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.client.JAXRSClientImpl.target(JAXRSClientImpl.java:109)
     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl.target(ClientImpl.java:100)
     at com.servengine.watson.naturallanguageclassifier.NaturalLanguageClassifierRESTClient.classify(NaturalLanguageClassifierRESTClient.java:161)
     at com.servengine.watson.naturallanguageclassifier.NaturalLanguageClassifierRESTClient$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.classify(Unknown Source)
     at com.skios.eliza.nlq.NaturalLanguageQueryFlowView$1.call(NaturalLanguageQueryFlowView.java:66)
     at com.skios.eliza.nlq.NaturalLanguageQueryFlowView$1.call(NaturalLanguageQueryFlowView.java:1)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

CXF cannot be used out of "main" Thread? What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you submitting the async work?  Have you tried using ManagedExecutorService?  Perhaps the implementation requires some thread context that is unavailable.

Comment: I have tried with ExecutorService (Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) using a Callable that returns a Future object. As this failed I recoded it using plain old Thread method executed with run, and fails too. I see this ManagedExecutorService is part of JEE7 but my view class is not a EJB (It is a Named CDI ApplicationScoped class). I'll test it in an EJB with the ManagedExecutorService to see if it makes any difference. Thanks

Comment: Sure, see if it works.  I'm really just speculating though.  Given that this is an NPE in IBM code, you might get a quicker response from an IBM forum or from IBM support (I know people from IBM monitor the websphere-liberty tag, but they might not be familiar with the JAX-RS internals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the client API in a forked new thread, you need to make sure the new thread is a container managed one. In your case, you can enable concurrent-1.0 feature. Then use:

@Resource(name="java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorServcie") 
ManagedExecutorService executor;

```
 Task task = new Task();    
 Future<String> result = executor.submit(task);
```

In Your Task class, you can do the same thing with what you done before: WebTarget myResource = client.target(apiURLBase + ...);

Comment: Hello, I didn't use Resource as I am not sure that JDNI is standard and will work in other EJB containers (not Liberty) so I tried using a Asynchronous annotated method in a Stateless EJB which performs the REST request. Method returns a Future<> answer with the response object. It just worked. I guess Future methods also use container managed threads. Thanks a lot for your help.