# Quartz scheduled job on Liberty app-server calling REST throwing exception

Tags: quartz-scheduler, jersey-2.0, websphere-liberty

I'm having real hassle getting a quartz job in an application server to call a REST service - totally puzzled (:

I have quartz (v 2.2.2) deployed & working on an IBM Liberty Application Server (v 8.5.5.8) with Java 1.8
It scans a directory for files and then calls my Dummy Task.

However, when I replace the Dummy Task with a REST WebClient call - I get a pretty odd stacktrace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
[err] at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.client.bus.LibertyJAXRSClientBusFactory.getClientScopeBus(LibertyJAXRSClientBusFactory.java:89)
[err] at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.client.JAXRSClientImpl.target(JAXRSClientImpl.java:109)
[err] at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl.target(ClientImpl.java:100)
[err] at notification.server.rest.MyIBMHandler.testClient4(MyIBMHandler.java:61)
```

the last line is mine and the code I wrote is simply based on this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_jaxrs2.0_clientconfig.html

When I googled the exception above, I didn't see much except for one stacktrace related one:-
[NullPointerException when running CXF JAX-RS 2.0 client "target" method in Liberty Profile under a Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922438/nullpointerexception-when-running-cxf-jax-rs-2-0-client-target-method-in-liber) 
Which leads me to believe there may be some form of a threading conflict here.

To prove my REST client code was ok on my Liberty app-server, I did put my REST methodinto a servlet and call it there and it did work fine.
i.e.

```
public void testClient4() {
    javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder cb = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
    javax.ws.rs.client.Client c = cb.build();
    String res = null;

    try {
        String resourceURL = "http://localhost:9080/SampleRest/sample/";
        res = c.target(resourceURL).path("Greeting").request().get(String.class);
        System.out.println("res:" + res);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        res = "[Error]:" + e.toString();
        System.err.println("error:" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (c != null)
            c.close();
        System.out.println("res:" + res);
    }
}
```

My Quartz props are close to out of the box, here is the threadpool section:-

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 4
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
```

My job class uses the annotation - @DisallowConcurrentExecution

I'm using the jersey 2.17 libs & jackson libs
I've added lots of features to my Liberty profile - i.e.

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
    <feature>apiDiscovery-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrsClient-2.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

For now, the REST service being called is a simple one.
When running quartz within an app-server, do I need to do anyconfig to be able to call a REST service? - anyone got this working?

Comment: I think you may have tripped over a bug in WebSphere but don't know enough to suggest a workaround, sorry.

Comment: Try remove Jersey and jakson libs from your application, since they are provided by Liberty, when you enable jaxrs features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears we fixed this NPE in the latest Liberty fixpack, looking [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27004980#ver85_0), the 8.5.5.9 fixpack is planned to be available on March 18.  Once released, please test and determine if it fixes this problem, and if not let us know.

Comment: Yes, fp 8.5.5.9 definitely appears to have fixed the issues I was encountering. My scheduled task is now running as expected.